# JS function that is running after a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, smooth-scrolling

I have two functions. I am wanting to combine them so that when you are moving left-to-right (or vice-versa) it does not have a delay (like the scroll down function does).

```js
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});


$(function(){
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var $target = $(this.hash);
            $target = $target.length && $target || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if ($target.length) {
                var targetOffset = $target.offset().left;
                $('html,body').animate({scrollLeft: targetOffset}, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#Home{
    position:relative;
 width:100vw;
 height:100vh;
 background-color:#FFF;
}

#SectionLeft{
    position:relative;
 width:100vw;
 height:100vh;
 background-color:#989898;
 float:left;
}

#SectionRight{
    position:relative;
 margin-left:100vw;
 width:100vw;
 height:100vh;
    color:000;
 background-color:#838383;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="Home">
    <a href="#SectionLeft">Go Down</a>
</div>
         
<div id="SectionLeft">
     <a href="#SectionRight">Go Right</a>   
</div>

<div id="SectionRight">
     <a href="#SectionLeft">Go Left</a>   
</div>
```

Comment: Look up for **setTimeout in javascript**

Comment: Wait, do you want a delay or not? What scroll down function are you talking about?

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal this has nothing to do with question regarding how i understand it

Comment: As you can see when you click "Go down" it immediately goes to the div directed in the link. However, when clicking on "Go Right" and "Go Left" there is a delay that I am not sure from where it is coming. I want to remove this delay so it can be the same as when the user is moving Up-down through the page. I hope you can understand me now better.

Comment: You are firstly calling scroll top on this element which takes one second to complete even it is scrolling to same value (meaning scrolling vertically to 0). `animate()` method use fx queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As you can see when you click "Go down" it immediately goes to the div
>   directed in the link. However, when clicking on "Go Right" and "Go
>   Left" there is a delay that I am not sure from where it is coming.

You are firstly calling scroll top on this element which takes one second to complete even it is scrolling to same value (meaning scrolling vertically to 0). `animate()` method uses fx queue so all animations are put in queue, running only one at once.

```js
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top,
          scrollLeft: target.offset().left
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#Home{
    position:relative;
 width:100vw;
 height:100vh;
 background-color:#FFF;
}

#SectionLeft{
    position:relative;
 width:100vw;
 height:100vh;
 background-color:#989898;
 float:left;
}

#SectionRight{
    position:relative;
 margin-left:100vw;
 width:100vw;
 height:100vh;
    color:000;
 background-color:#838383;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="Home">
    <a href="#SectionLeft">Go Down</a>
</div>
         
<div id="SectionLeft">
     <a href="#SectionRight">Go Right</a>   
</div>

<div id="SectionRight">
     <a href="#SectionLeft">Go Left</a>   
</div>
```

Comment: That did the job. Thank you very much, I am really grateful !

Comment: @DimchoStoimenov FYI, if you want to still use two different handlers (even you said not in question), you could set for each `animate()` method otpion `queue: false`

Answer (score 1):

Try adjusting selectors , adding `#SectionRight a` , `#SectionLeft a` to `:not()` at first `.animate()` ; using `'#SectionLeft a, #SectionRight a'` at second `.animate()`

```js
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#], #SectionLeft a, #SectionRight a)').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});


$(function(){
    $('#SectionLeft a, #SectionRight a').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var $target = $(this.hash);
            $target = $target.length && $target || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if ($target.length) {
                var targetOffset = $target.offset().left;
                $('html,body').animate({scrollLeft: targetOffset}, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#Home{
    position:relative;
 width:100vw;
 height:100vh;
 background-color:#FFF;
}

#SectionLeft{
    position:relative;
 width:100vw;
 height:100vh;
 background-color:#989898;
 float:left;
}

#SectionRight{
    position:relative;
 margin-left:100vw;
 width:100vw;
 height:100vh;
    color:000;
 background-color:#838383;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="Home">
    <a href="#SectionLeft">Go Down</a>
</div>
         
<div id="SectionLeft">
     <a href="#SectionRight">Go Right</a>   
</div>

<div id="SectionRight">
     <a href="#SectionLeft">Go Left</a>   
</div>
```

Comment: `$.fx.interval = -10000;` cannot be negative otherwise 0 is assumed and anyway the issue is regarding fx queue

Comment: @A.Wolff Have previously utilized negative number ; can link to documentation where `0` is assumed if number is negative ? See updated post ; adjusted selectors . Though your solution reduces `js` by half

Comment: That's relevant part in jq source regarding `$.fx.interval`: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=fx.interval  That's just using js interval. Here is relevant doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval#Specification  `As with setTimeout, there is a minimum delay enforced.`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Notes  Anyway, using negative value would mean code should be executed **before** it is called, so this is quite pointless :)